# Django: Best Query for a Normal Distribution

Tags: django, django-models

I'm making data analysis in Django and I'm trying to create a database query that can iterate over a model and print out the amount of rows within an interval.

The problem is that the total amount of results varies. If "interval" is changed the "total" will also change. 
Why does it do that?

```
# Get the data
data = COPD6Model.objects.filter(patient=patients)
# Calculate the min and max value
max_min = data.aggregate(Max("fev1_procent"), Min("fev1_procent"))
max = float(max_min.get("fev1_procent__max"))
min = float(max_min.get("fev1_procent__min")) - float(interval)
# Set the interval
interval = 2.0
total = 0
# Iterate over the query
for start in numpy.arange(min, max, interval):
    end = start + interval
    result = len(data.filter(fev1_procent__gt=start, fev1_procent__lte=end))
    total += result
print total
```

Comment: Just a side note, you could use `queryset.count()` instead of `len(queryset)`

Comment: Also, can you clarify why are you subtracting `float(interval)` when first calculating `min`?

Comment: Yes, because the query only looks for "greater than start" values. So if the minimum value equals the start value it will not be counted (only in the first iteration). Thats why I'm setting the "min" value lower than the actual minimum value. I hope it make sens!

Comment: Try printing the elements that get counted on each iteration. Perhaps there is a hidden issue with float precision.

Comment: You are correct. Its the float that messes things up. If I use the Decimal number instead of a float then the algorithm behaves accordingly. 
If you write an answer with you answer then I'm able to reward you with 25 points. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a problem with float precision. Use decimal instead of float.